# flutter- I don't know the difference between these two case

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

Case 1 :

```
    children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES.map((catData) {
      CategoryItem(
        catData.title,
        catData.color,
      );
    }).toList(),
```

Case 2 :

```
    children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
        .map(
          (catData) => CategoryItem(
                catData.title,
                catData.color,
              ),
        )
        .toList(),
```

Case 1 causes an error.
Isn't the two cases the same syntax?
Why is this error occurring?

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
GridView
lib\categories_screen.dart:12
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: You are missing return keyword before 'CategoryItem' in case 1. Case 2 returns immediatelly after arrow.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 2** uses the **Fat Arrow Expression** or **Lambda Function Expression**, a syntax to write a function on a single line using => syntax AKA fat arrow. [more info](https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-functions-and-fat-arrow-expression-d9ce8e22c2da)

```
DUMMY_CATEGORIES.map(
  (catData) => CategoryItem(
    catData.title,
    catData.color,
  ),
).toList(),
```

**Fat Arrow Syntax:**

```
(args) => expression
```

If `expression` has a return type (in your case, a CategoryItem), it directly returns.

It is the same as your **Case 1** with a return statement:

```
DUMMY_CATEGORIES.map(
  (catData) {
    return CategoryItem(
      catData.title,
      catData.color,
    ),
  }
).toList(),
```